# Probability Statistics

Tags: probability

Statistics show that 3% of tomatoes come off the production line contaminated. If two tomatoes were picked what is the probability that;
1.  Both are contaminated
2.  Only one is contaminated
3.  Both are contaminated

Would the answers be

1. 6% (0.06)
2. 3% (0.03)
3. 94% (0.94)

Comment: also for 3, are you trying to ask when none are contaminated?

Comment: Yes sorry, for 3 both are not contaminated.

Comment: you would be correct, if it was without replacement. I think this is without replacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that $(3)$ should read: "Both are **not** contaminated. Otherwise, it repeats $(1)$. I will also assume that the two tomatoes are picked randomly.

$(1)\quad$ The probability of picking one contaminated tomato is $3\% = \dfrac 3{100}$. We use the rule of the product to compute the probability of selecting *two* contaminated tomatoes is then $$\dfrac{3}{100}\times \dfrac{3}{100} = \dfrac {9}{10000}= 0.0009$$

$(2)\quad$ The probability of selecting two tomatoes where (exactly) one tomato of two is contaminated is the probability of selecting a contaminated tomato, multiplied by the probability of selecting a **non** -contaminated tomato: $$\dfrac{3}{100}\times \left( 1 - \dfrac{3}{100}\right)=0.0291$$

$(3)\quad $ Now, using the rule of the product, what is the probability that *each* of two randomly selected tomato is **not** contaminated?

Comment: (1 - 3/100) * (1 - 3/100) = 0.9409 ?

Comment: Yes, you got it!

Comment: Thank you amWhy, much appreciated